# file create and delete in a thread do not work in the android app when invoked again

Tags: android, file-io

In a particular audio record program I am creating a new file, writing audio data to it, closing the file and deleting it. This works when I do this in a thread the first time. But when I kill the thread and start the thread again the old files remain the same and newly recorded audio does not get written to the same file. I cant understand this strange behavior. Could some one point out what could be wrong?

Added code as per comment

```
 public void startRecording() {
    if (mThread != null)
        return;

    mShouldContinue = true;
    mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            record();
        }
    });
    mThread.start();
}

 public void stop() {
    //synchronized (mLock) {
      //  dismiss();
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
           // mThread.stop();
            mThread = null;
        }

        mBuffer = null;
    //}
}
```

Above are my start recording and stop recording functions where I create and kill a thread respectively. Now I will add parts of the record function here.

```
 public void record() {
AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            //AudioFormat.THREE_GPP,
            bufferSize);


    if (record.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Audio Record can't initialize!");
        return;
    }
    record.startRecording();
 String AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME = "recording2.wav";
    String AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME1 = "recordingb.raw";
    String AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME2 = "temp.raw";
    String AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME3 = "pure.raw";
    String AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME4 = "test.pcm";
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            // String filePath = Environment.get().getPath()
            + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME;
    //String filePath1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    //      + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME1;
    String filePath2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME2;
    String filePath3 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME3;
    String filePath4 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME4;
    BufferedOutputStream os = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataOutputStream pos = null;
    File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");
    //File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "recording2.wav");
    OutputStream outputStream1;// = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream1;// = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream1);
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream1;
try {
        os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath3));
        // dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath1));
        pos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath2));
//do some processing here and then write data to file and close
try{
                for (int i = 0; i < nos / 2; i++) {
                    dataOutputStream1.writeShort(prightChannelAudioData[runtimes][i]);

                    //os.write(bData,0,3584*2);
                }
        }catch (IOException et) {
                et.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte bData[] = short2byte(prightChannelAudioData[runtimes]);
            os.write(bData, 0, bData.length);
            //byte bData[] = short2byte(trightChannelAudioData);
        }
        dataOutputStream1.close();
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    copyWaveFile(filePath3, filePath);
        file1.delete();
        record.stop();
```

But when I call the thread again, none of the files get re-written again but contain only the old audio...So where am I going wrong?

Comment: It is hard to say anything without code. Show us what you have already done.

Comment: I added the code as you suggested..

Comment: Solved. The thread was getting null in stop. So if I dont null it,I can call it the second time and the audio files get updated. In many audio recording apps in android the runnable is extended to a audio record function. If we dont null the thread, then we can continue to use the function again and again. Just a single line of code with 2 words was making the difference..